Why for finding the transverse traceless gauge the energy-momentum tensor is set to 0?
I was reading the Introduction to General Relativity by Carroll, SG and found this when obtaining the transverse traceless gauge, my questions are:

How you justify this condition?
Which are the physical implications of it?

I simply don't understand why that imposition is made and for me it seems out of the blue.
Thanks for reading


Which condition are you talking about, exactly? If it's the gauge, then the whole point of a gauge is that you can choose whatever is convenient, right? (If you disagree, it might be good to present your understanding of what a gauge choice means so answers can see where the confusion lies) If it's the $T=0$, then can you not derive from the meaning of energy-momentum in general what it means?

The answer is already present in the text you posted. Recall the physical interpretation of the energy-momentum tensor, and then see what the text says about this concept. Also, the condition of $T_{\mu\nu} = 0$ is irrelevant for the construction of the TT-gauge - it just simplifies the calculations and makes the underlying physical concepts more apparent from the equations.

@paulina that is what I don't understand, I don't understand why since is not necesary which are the calculations that is simplifying, Maybe I'm not seeing how it goues from that condition to de perturbation metric
